# Knowledge article link to a Content Management System PDF - downloads rather than previews

Tags: knowledge, salesforce-cms

- If I upload a PDF file to SFDC CMS workspace associated with my guest user Experience Site
- Then create a link to that PDF within the rich text portion of an Knowledge Article like this:

  https://mydomain.my.site.com/help/cms/delivery/media/MC4H22ZI2XDJFUHHOJ45PZXXXXXX

then, on the guest Site, **when a user clicks the link**:

| Browser | Result | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chrome | PDF downloads | Even when Chrome Settings **Open PDF in Chrome** is enabled |
| Firefox | PDF renders in new browser tab |  |
| Safari | PDF downloads |  |

If instead I upload the PDF as a File and generate a public link and have the Knowledge article include a link to that file, then for all browsers ...

- The PDF opens in a new browser tab
- But the URL is for the SFDC org's domain - e.g. `https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com`, not the Experience site's domain.

SFDC Support asserts this is all **Working-as-designed** but one would think one could have

- the entire user "experience" while reading Knowledge Articles and
- clicking links to SFDC Content Management System PDFs
- that the PDF renders in new browser tabs ***with the Experience Site's domain***.

Is there a trick that I'm missing?

Comment: Custom code that understands mydomain.site.com/foo/article ->  your Apex that calls CMS API -> send PDF with the right [content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-do-i-force-files-to-open-in-the-browser-instead-of-downloading-pdf), thus no download.  Have not tried this with a PDF but we've done it plenty of times with other content.

Comment: @identigral - not sure I understand, I just want to have a Knowledge article rich text body link to CMS PDF docs - where would apex even get involved here?

Comment: To render the PDF in the new tab, you need the right content-type and possibly some other browser-specific tweaks. Thus, custom code that reimplements what you want.

Comment: oh -- the Knowledge Article rich text link is not directly to the CMS but rather to some intermediate code (passing the contentId of the CMS item) that then deals with the rendering of the PDFs per browser vagaries. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: Yup, you got it.

Comment: ...a bonus of this approach and the reason why we do it: vanity and search engine friendly URLs. Instead of mydomain.site.com/ootb/blah/<contentid> or /my/custom?contentId=MC4H22ZI2XDJFUHHOJ45PZXXXXXX , we have mydomain.site.com/article/about/the/birds , translating `/about/the/birds` to MC4H22ZI2XDJFUHHOJ45PZXXXXXX in this simple example.

Comment: @identigral - you should post as an answer